# What is the time complexity of the following method?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to understand how to check time complexity but I cannot solve this example:

Image :

[image: The original problem, as an image.]

Could someone help me solve it and explain how to do it step by step?

Comment: Is this your homework? Would you mind sharing any attempts you have done so far?

Comment: Please refer to point 3 in [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions about homework

Comment: @LeandroHernándezMira No, it's O(log m).

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm loops until m reaches 0.  In each iteration m is either halved (if it was even) or reduced by 1 (if it was odd).  If the algorithm would just halve m in each iteration, then this would take log(m) steps (in the context of complexity, log() is typically meant to be of base 2).  In our case, however, we might have at most double the amount of iterations, namely if after each halving of an even number we get an odd number.  These odd numbers are reduced by 1 which results in creating the next even number.

Doubling the amount of steps is a constant factor which isn't taken into account when calculating complexities in the Big-O notation, so the complexity stays at O(log(n)).